# Using an AND in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a worksheet that is used to enter data that is then transferred to a log on a second sheet.

I want to have an if statement in place that stops people from doing duplicate updates. Currently I have a code that stops it updating if one cell is the same as the corresponding last cell of the log but I want to repeat this with 1 or 2 more cells in case the usual 'matching' cell needs to be the same for any reason.

I'm new to VBA, i've tried to play about with `else if`else if and `and` but had no luck, I think I am maybe struggling with the structure of these though.

My `And` would need to go after the first if statement so if the first statement is false the second one will be true to stop the log from being updated.

```
Dim WkBk    As Workbook
Dim WkSht   As Worksheet

 Set WkBk = ThisWorkbook


Set WkSht = WkBk.Worksheets("Log")


    If (WkBk.Worksheets("Data").Range("I17") = WkSht.Range("N" & WkSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) Then 


           MsgBox "This entry has already been logged"

Set WkSht = Nothing
Set WkBk = Nothing
Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: You may need to explain a little more clearly.  Where would your `And` go? in VBA, it'd look like `If myString = "words" and Len(myString) > 0 and myString <> "how" Then ...`.   Also, your `Then` needs to be on the same line as the `If` statement.

Comment: ~While i <= lastrow
If Cells(i, "A") like "*Paris*" And Cells(i, "D") like "*Zurich*" Then
Cells(i, "C").Value = "CA"
End If~

Comment: If this is always in the same range why not use `find` and if it gets a match then trigger the `MsgBox`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the find function here, it can search the entire column for you.

I have then used a 'If Not' and 'Is Nothing' so if find gets something then your message box will appear. This is the best way to go about finding duplicated values in VBA coding:

```
Dim RngFound As Range
Dim StrData As String

 StrData = Worksheets("Data").Range("I17")
 Worksheets("Log").Activate
    Set RngFound = Columns("N").Find(StrData, Range("N1"), xlValues, xlPart)
    If Not RngFound Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "This entry has already been logged"
    End If

    Set RngFound = Nothing
    Set WkSht = Nothing
    Set WkBk = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is taking me to the last cell of the whole log. I need to check a specific cell on the last row of the log.